# Синтаксис SQL table.column

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
```

Увидил недавно вот такой синтаксис SQL запроса в MySQL

Вопросы:

Во всех SQL запросах допустимо использовать конструкции типа table.column?

Как такие конструкции называются и где об этом можно прочитать (желательно в документации по MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Вместо имени столбца можно использовать table.column, это особенно удобно в случае джойна таблиц с одинаковыми именами столбцов. Кроме имени таблиц можно использовать их алиасы `select u.name from users as u;`, что тоже часто встречается. Подробнее об этом можно прочитать в [документации MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз то, что я искал